# Set first paragraph no indentation after re-definition of section

Tags: sectioning, indentation, paragraphs

I'm trying to avoid the indentation of the first paragraph that is introduced by the `SciTePress.sty` style. I think that the problem is the redefinition of `\section` within the style. Because, if I remove it the first paragraph after section header isn't indented.

My question is, how can I change the behavior of the `\section` command to "no indent after section"? I think that I have to redefine it within my code, because I can't change the given style. Also, can I make the section title uppercase at the same time in the same redefinition?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}


\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{SciTePress}
\usepackage[small]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\title{\uppercase{Authors' Instructions}  \subtitle{Preparation of Camera-Ready Contributions to SciTePress Proceedings} }

\author{\authorname{First Author Name\sup{1}, Second Author Name\sup{1} and Third Author Name\sup{2}}
\affiliation{\sup{1}Institute of Problem Solving, XYZ University, My Street, MyTown, MyCountry}
\affiliation{\sup{2}Department of Computing, Main University, MySecondTown, MyCountry}
\email{\{f\_author, s\_author\}@ips.xyz.edu, t\_author@dc.mu.edu}
}

\keywords{\lipsum[1]}

\abstract{\lipsum[2]}

\onecolumn \maketitle \normalsize \vfill

\section{\uppercase{Introduction}}

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

**SciTePress.sty**

```
\typeout{Conference Style for SciTePress for LaTeX 2e -- version of March 2011}
%Modified by L. Medina:
%   - title, authors, keywords and abstract: commands redefinition
%   - spaces above and below captions: redefinition

%Modified by V. Pedrosa:
%   - title, authors, keywords and abstract: spacing is now automatic

%%Page Setup

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\paperheight{297mm}
\setlength\paperwidth{210mm}


\setlength\topmargin{-0.91in} \setlength\oddsidemargin{0.02362in}
\setlength\evensidemargin{0.02362in}

\setlength\textheight{8.74in} \setlength\textwidth{6.221in}
\setlength\columnsep{0.8cm}
\newlength\titlebox %\setlength\titlebox{2in}
\setlength\headheight{0pt} \setlength\headsep{36pt}
\thispagestyle{empty} \pagestyle{empty}

\flushbottom \twocolumn \sloppy

\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}



%%First Section
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{ #1 \\[15pt]{\textmd {\textbf }}\\}}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\\ \fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont \textit{#1 } }

\def\keywords#1{\gdef\@keywords{\small Keywords: \hspace{0.388cm} \begin{minipage}[t]{5.45in} \fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont \vspace{-0.22cm} #1 \\ \end{minipage}}}
%\gdef\@mykeywords{}
\def\abstract#1{\gdef\@abstract{\ \\ \small Abstract: \hspace{0.6cm} \begin{minipage}[t]{5.45in}  \fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont \vspace{-0.22cm} #1 \end{minipage} }}

%%%%%%%
\def\sup#1{$^{#1}$}

\newcommand{\authorname}[1]{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont #1 \\ }%\addtocounter{authorcounter}{1}}
\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{6.2in} \centering \fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont \textit{ #1} \end{minipage} \\}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont  \textit{#1} \\[12pt]}


%%%%%%%
\def\maketitle{\par
\begingroup
% to make the footnote style local to the title
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\twocolumn[

\centering {\LARGE\bf \@title \par}
\vskip -0.07in

\centering\@author
\vskip 0.51in

\@keywords
\vskip 0.02in

\@abstract

\vspace{32pt}

]


\@thanks
\endgroup

\let\maketitle\relax \let\@maketitle\relax
\gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}



%%Paper Contents and References

\def\pubnote#1{\thispagestyle{myheadings}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{#1}{#1}
\setlength\headheight{10pt}  \setlength\headsep{10pt}
}

% sections with less space
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Remove this definition and the indentation returns!
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{24pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{\Large\bf\raggedright}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-2.0ex plus
-0.5ex minus -.2ex}{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{\large\bf\raggedright}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-2.0ex plus
-0.5ex minus -.2ex}{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{\normalsize\bf\raggedright}}


% Footnotes
\footnotesep 6.65pt %
\skip\footins 9pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3pt \hrule width 5pc \kern 2.6pt }

% Lists and paragraphs
\parindent 0.5cm
\topsep 4pt plus 1pt minus 2pt
\partopsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
\itemsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
\parsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
\leftmargin 15pt \leftmargini\leftmargin \leftmarginii 10pt
\leftmarginiii 5pt \leftmarginiv 5pt \leftmarginv 5pt \leftmarginvi
5pt \labelwidth\leftmargini\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep \labelsep
5pt
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini}
\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
\labelwidth\leftmarginii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
\topsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 0.5pt
\parsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
\itemsep \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
\labelwidth\leftmarginiii\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
\topsep 1pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt
\parsep \z@ \partopsep 0.5pt plus 0pt minus 0.5pt
\itemsep \topsep}
\def\@listiv{\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
\labelwidth\leftmarginiv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv{\leftmargin\leftmarginv
\labelwidth\leftmarginv\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi{\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
\labelwidth\leftmarginvi\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\abovedisplayskip 7pt plus2pt minus5pt%
\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip 0pt plus3pt%
\belowdisplayshortskip 4pt plus3pt minus3pt%

%%%%%%
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{4pt}%plus3pt minus3pt}%
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-4pt}%plus3pt minus3pt}
%%%%%%
% Less leading in most fonts (due to the narrow columns)
% The choices were between 1-pt and 1.5-pt leading
\def\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{11}}   % 10 point on 11
\def\small{\@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{10}}    % 9 point on 10
\def\smalll{\@setfontsize\smalll\@viiipt{10}}    % 9 point on 9
\def\footnotesize{\@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{10}}  % 9 point on 10
\def\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt{10}}  % 7 point on 8
\def\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt{7}}    % 6 point on 7
\def\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xipt{12}}    % 11 point on 12
\def\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xiipt{14}}    % 12 point on 14
\def\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xivpt{16}}    % 14 point on 16
\def\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xviipt{20}}    % 17 point on 20
\def\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxpt{23}}    % 20 point on 23

\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.1cm} \addtolength{\textheight}{-0.1cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.9cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.7cm}

\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10}{11.5}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}

\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\T}{\mathcal{T}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathcal{R}}
\newcommand{\rr}{\mathfrak{r}}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\textsf{#1}}

\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.9}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make the `beforeskip` (the 4th argument to `\@startsection`) negative. The absolute value is always used, but if it is negative then the indent is ignored for the paragraph text following the heading.

```
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{24pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{\Large\bf\raggedright}}
```

Would then become

```
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-24pt plus -2pt minus -1pt}
{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}{\Large\bf\raggedright}}
```

And that should solve the problem. You can do this in your own source of course after loading the style), you then need to wrap it with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because the `@` symbol is used in the macro definition.

Some more information about the `\@startsection` macro can be found on [this website](http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-sections.shtml).

Comment: And you can add `\uppercase` after the `\Large\bf\raggedright` commands.