# How do I stop indenting first paragraphs when using amsbook style?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, amsbook

I'm using amsbook style and I'd like first paragraphs to be not indented - what can I add to the header to do this?

I don't want to use /noindent as then I'd have to use it all the way through my 200 page document, I'd prefer to do it automatically.

Comment: `\noindent` can be invoked before the first paragraph.

Comment: But I'd prefer not to have to add that throughout my entire thesis.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40510/set-first-paragraph-no-indentation-after-re-definition-of-section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine `\section`. The relevant part of `amsbook.cls` is

```
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}}
```

You want this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{-.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}}
\makeatother
```

Note the negative value `-.7`.

Use`\makeatletter ... \makeatother` if you don't want to edit `amsbook.cls`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\begin{document}
\noindent Don't be lukewarm. If you cannot be the best, be the worst.

Second paragraph here\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that would work but I'd have to do it throughout my whole document and I'm sure there is a better way.